# Get max value when joining 3 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql

This is based on a MySQL database.

I'm trying to join 3 tables together and get a MAX value from the third one. I'm trying to get the po.id, for each part.id, that has the latest po.date. I cannot base it on the MAX po.id. It must be based on the MAX po.date, which is what I'm stuck on. However, I need to used the poitem table to determine if the po contains the part.

Table: po

`po.id`, `po.date`

Table: poitem

`poitem.id` (item id that is only used for joining), `poitem.partid`

Table: part

`part.id`

This is what I'm trying to end up with:

`part.id                po.id`

`.....                  .....`

`.....                  .....`

`.....                  .....`

Comment: whar happens when Max po.date gas two ids or even more?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that  poitem.id is the same as po.id

```
SELECT
     pa.id,
     pi.id
FROM
    part pa INNER JOIN poitem pi ON pi.partid = pa.id
WHERE pi.id IN (SELECT po.id 
                FROM po 
                WHERE po.`date` = (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM po))
```